# How to print GranTotal on Transactional email Magento 1.8

Tags: php, email, magento, transactional

I'm trying to print GranTotal on email when a customer make a new order, right now I have used those variables on System → Transactional Emails:

(a)

```
{{var Total}}
```

**But doesn't show total**

(b)

```
{{var order.getGrandTotal()}}
```

**But I´m getting a reply with 4 decimals such as: 1900,0000 And we don't use decimals, so that reply confuses my customers.**

I will appreciate a full reply of what I could do... Thanks!

Comment: Can you use a function like number_format? You should be able to remove the digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the template parameters to format to two decimal places.

e.g.
Search your codebase for:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(
```

When you find the transnational email you want to modify (in this case it seems you want to edit new order emails, so likely in this file:

```
app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php
```

Copy the file to:

```
app\code\local\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php
```

Then edit the following code:

FROM:

```
    $mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
        'order'        => $this,
        'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
        'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
    ));
```

TO:

```
$mailer->setTemplateParams(array(
    'formatted_total' => sprintf('%.2F', $this->getData( 'grand_total' ) ),
    'order'        => $this,
    'billing'      => $this->getBillingAddress(),
    'payment_html' => $paymentBlockHtml
));
```

To get the thousands separator use:

```
    'formatted_total' => number_format( $this->getData( 'grand_total' ), 2, '.', ',' ),
```

Then edit the email template:

```
app/locale/en_US/template/email/sales/order_new.html
```

To output the new variable where you want it to appear.

```
var formatted_total
```

Comment: Thanks @Vladimir-Ramik  its worked, but I have two doubts ... I'm a DIY on Magento, and I always heard that modify Core files is not the best way to do thing on magento... it is correct? and... is possible to add a thousands separator? such as: 1.000 ? ( dot for thousands separator) right now is showing: 1000 and it woul be great to have "1.000"  Thanks again!

Comment: You are correct. Editing answer to include additional info